# If-Else not working as expected if found matching element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where user can fill details and on clicking of add attendee button can add up to 9 people details. I am getting value of user name, selected checkbox item id and item quantity and storing inside array and passing these values in URL to add selected items and created user. On first click I'm checking if item is already there in array.

[image: screenshot of form]

On first click I'm adding id's and quantity in array what I want to achieve is to increase quantity of that id which is already present in array, each time i click on this button it checks array and update quantity if its already present but its not working.

Here is my code

```
jQuery("#btnadd2").click(function() {
    var qty;
    var allVals = [];
    var nameatt = jQuery("#txtAttendeeNames").val();
    var nameatt= jQuery("#txtAttendeeNames").val();
    var emattendee= jQuery("#txtAttendeeEmails").val();
    var eventname = jQuery("#hdEventName").val();
    var eventlocation = jQuery("#hdLocation").val();
    jQuery(".big:checked").each(function() {
        qty = parseInt(jQuery(this).parents().nextAll().children().find('input[name="quantity"]').val());
        if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), allVals) == -1) {
            allVals.push(jQuery(this).val()); //not present in array     
        } else {
            qty = parseInt(jQuery(this).parents().nextAll().children().find('input[name="quantity"]').val() + 1);
        }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < allVals.length; i++) {
        var rslt = allVals.join(',' + qty + ',' + 'custcol_name_of_attendees|' + nameatt + '||custcol_email_o f_attendees|' + emattendee + '||custcol_event_name|' + eventname + '||custcol_event_location|' + eventlocation + ';');
        rslt1 = jQuery('#txtCntNameReg').val(rslt);
        console.log(rslt1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code has a bunch of undeclared variables (`emattendee` and others). Please declare every single variable you use with `var` first.

Comment: Without your HTML code it's  not easy to help here.

Comment: I am getting quantity value but not updating in the url...what is wrong in my code

Comment: You are overwriting your variables `qty` and `rslt` in every loop iteration. That can't be right. Also I think you have not understood how Array#join() is supposed to be used.

Comment: I just want to know should i add anything in else part to make it update quantity because if is working fine and i am able to construct url

Comment: Yeah, you're using .join in a really weird way, but I think your issue is you're overwriting variables when you iterate over the checked boxes. Consider writing a function constructor to encapsulate the data for your fields, and then create an array that you can populate with them..

Comment: What's the purpose of the `for()` loop at the end? You never use `i` or `allVals[i]` in the loop.

Comment: By this loop i'm appending custcol_name_of_attendees and other custom fields values to each array element in url....these are my custom fields created in netsuite....netsuite uses this format to pass values in url

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
qty = qty + 1;
```

instead of this,

```
qty = parseInt(jQuery(this).parents().nextAll().children().find('input[name="quantity"]').val() + 1);
```

in else condition.

Comment: Add attendee button is not reloading the page so i guess function is not storing array...else part is not running